# Android onDateSet method of DatePicker does not set text of textview in another open dialog

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have a dialog window with a textView which shows the date selected by datePicker. I also have a button on this dialog that opens a datePicker (fragment) and lets me select a date. However, when I press ok the date textView does not get set in the dialog window. But if I debug this there definitely is information of the date being passed, the problem is that it does not get set in the dialog.

The code for the onDateSet is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_edit, null);

    TextView txtDate = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    txtDate.setText(year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth);
}
```

This code is from the main activity page.

When I debug this the year,month and dayofmonth all have the right value. But the txtDate.setText doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

@RedZerg We are real late to this party First we do not use the Fragment to store my DatePicker we put it in its own XML file where the root layout is a vertical LinearLayout that way it does not clutter the Activity Screen we are picking from this code will send the selected DATE'S to another Activity my goal here was to pick two dates with one button and send the dates to do a BETWEEN SQL search on DB We use a styles to manage the styling

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/color_lightGray">
    <!--the background sets the color of the calender  -->

    <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:headerBackground="@color/color_Purple"
    android:theme="@style/DatePickerTheme" />
   </LinearLayout>

    <style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/color_Purple</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_Black</item>
</style>

    public void onMake(View view){

    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PageOneActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datepickerview);
    // the layout datepickerview is a XML file
    dialog.setTitle("");

    DatePicker picker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    // the id datePicker is a Date Picker widget in its own XML file
    // as referenced above you need this to manage custom styling
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //picker.updateDate(2017, 10, 13);//year month day
    picker.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);// Keeps Calendar initial view what ever today is!

    //Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM"+"-"+"dd"+"-"+"yyyy");
    //String folderName = formatter.format(today);

    System.out.println("Month " + mMonth+1);

    picker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    //picker.init(Integer.valueOf(mMonth),Integer.valueOf(mDay),Integer.valueOf(mYear), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker picker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            if (txtDateOne.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("I am Not Empty");
                txtDateOne.setText((monthOfYear+1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year);
                etFirstDate.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1 ) + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + String.valueOf(year));
                v1 = Long.valueOf(etFirstDate.getText().toString());
                etFirstDate.setText(String.valueOf(v1));
                //got1 = mDay;
                dialog.dismiss();

            } else {

                txtDateTwo.setText((monthOfYear+1 ) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year);
                etSecondDate.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + String.valueOf(year));
                v2 = Long.valueOf(etSecondDate.getText().toString());
                //v2 = Long.valueOf(txtDateTwo.getText().toString());
                etSecondDate.setText(String.valueOf(v2));
                dialog.dismiss();


                if (etSecondDate.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    if (v2 >= v1) {
                        btnDatePicker.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.color_Purple));
                        btnDatePicker.setEnabled(false);
                        sbstring = "First Date < or = Second Date";
                        Toast.makeText( PageOneActivity.this, "First Date < or = Second Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        //showSB();
                        int r = (int) (v2-v1);

                        //txtDateTwo.setText(String.valueOf(r));
                    } else {
                        btnDatePicker.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.color_deepBlue));
                        btnDatePicker.setEnabled(false);
                        sbstring = "First Date > or = Second Date";
                        Toast.makeText( PageOneActivity.this, "First Date > or = Second Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                        //showSB();
                        //int r = (int) (v1-v2);
                    }
                }
            }
            //mDay=dayOfMonth;
            //mMonth=(month);
            //mYear=year;
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

    public void onSend(View view){
    if(etFirstDate.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etSecondDate.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText( PageOneActivity.this, "You Need Both Dates\n       PICK A DATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        return;
    }else {
        Intent send = new Intent(PageOneActivity.this,PageTwoActivity.class);
        send.putExtra("FROM_DATE",v1);
        send.putExtra("TO_DATE",v2);
        startActivity(send);
    }
}
```